# Android Studio 'android.content' and 'android.view' sub classes are missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-view, android-context

In Android Studio packages **android.content** and **android.view** sub classes are missing,
sub claases like

- View
- Context
- LayoutInflater

i tried

- Invalidate Cache/ Restart
- Rebuild Project
- Clean
- Updated All Dependencies

but no one worked for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ow2D.png)

Comment: Have you checked SDK Manager?

Comment: @SujalKumar yes i checked, sdk is latest and sdk manager is working fine.

Comment: Switch to Project Mode and go to External Libraries -> Android API (Version) Platform -> android.jar -> android and then check if **view** etc folders are there or not.

Comment: @SujalKumar i checked some java files like Context,View are empty, what should i do for them ?

Comment: Delete and re-download the whole Android API from SDK manager. That's the only way I can see right now.

Comment: @SujalKumar Thank you so much, it wroked for me.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: I have posted an answer to avoid any future confusion for anyone else who faces this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone gets the same problem:
Delete and re-download the whole Android API from SDK Manager.